# Change value of a props in beforeDestroy/Destroyed cycle of child component does not work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hi I made a boolean value in parent component, and passed it to the child component as a props. it has initialized as false, and after the user view the component, the value will change to true, which means the page has been visited.

I have done some research and followed [How to properly pass data from child to parent and parent to child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440979/how-to-properly-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-and-parent-to-child-component)

here is my js code:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            hasLoad: {
                type: Boolean
            }
        },
        data () {
            return {
                hasLoadModel: this.hasLoad
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            console.log(this.hasLoad);
        },
        beforeDestroy: function() {
            this.hasLoadModel = true;
            this.hasLoad = true;
            console.log(this.hasLoadModel);
            console.log(this.hasLoad);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and html code

```
<div v-model="skillLoadModel">..</div>
```

But I still get

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
>   overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
>   data or computed property based on the prop's value.

I have tried to change the value at either of beforeDestroy or Destroyed, or do not use v-model, but none of them works. The value has changed after I left the page, but when I reenter the page, the value has reset to default value.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the value of the prop. Have the component [emit an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) so that the parent can take the appropriate action.

Below is an example of a component that is created when the checkbox is checked, and is destroyed when it gets unchecked. The component emits a "dying" event, and the parent receives it and prints a scream to the console.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showIt: true
  },
  methods: {
    scream() {
      console.log("Aaarg!");
    }
  },
  components: {
    myComponent: {
      beforeDestroy: function() {
        this.$emit('dying');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="showIt">
  <my-component v-if="showIt" hasload="true" @dying="scream" inline-template>
    <div>Here I am</div>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: I have read some documents, but it seems the emit can only fire when a click event is happened... could you give any advice that make a custom event which is not triggered by click?

Comment: hey thank you a lot! it almost works, I made a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/m5jtp37p/6/. I have a problem, I think after emit, the value in parent component has been set to true, but why in my child component is still false? I have to detect the value and write function depends on this boolean value in child component... do you have any recommendations?

Comment: After the emit, you need to wait for Vue to update things before the value will have changed. Use `$nextTick`, like in this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5jtp37p/17/).

Comment: Thanks man! it still had a few problems, and then I added the watch and now it works. https://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/m5jtp37p/47/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to communicate to the parent that the child has loaded.  In that case, you can pass a function as a `prop` and simply call it when the child mounts.

Parent HTML:

```
<child :my-load-fn="loadFn"></child>
```

Parent JS:

```
methods: {
  loadFn() {
    this.childHasLoaded = true
  }
}
```

Child JS:

```
props: ['myLoadFn'],
mounted() {
  this.myLoadFn()
}
```

Comment: Hi this sounds could work, but can I ask how I could use the childhasLoaded value in child component? my problem is that I am using css animation in child component, and it reloads every time when i enter the component, so I decide to toggle a class after the first time the user enter the component. I need the boolean value to toggle class